# How to make the width of the columns in the table equal？

Tags: tables, tabularx, width

I want to be able to reproduce this table exactly：
[image: fig1]
This is my Tex：

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\begin{document}
    
\begin{tabular}{ccccc}
    \cline{1-3}
    &  \makecell*{y \\ e}  & \makecell{$\kappa$ \\ eV $\si{\angstrom}^{-2}$ }\\ \hline 
    $\rm{Na}^+$   &  -0.5056            &  63.014 \\
    $\rm{Cl}^-$   &  -2.5005             &  25.724   \\
    \hline 
    1 & 2 &3  &4   &  5 \\ \hline 
    
\end{tabular}   
    
        
\end{document}
```

[image: fig]
Why is the width of the last line not equal? How should I modify it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like this?

[image]

**Edit:**

- In your MWE are not present contents of lower part of table, so in the following example considers only data in the upper part of table.
- The screenshot shows that the numbers in the second and third columns have many more digits than the numbers in the other columns. To get all columns to be equally wide, one has to replace the `c` column type, which uses the "natural" width of the cells in a column, with a fixed width.
- For your test table, I suggest you use the `w` column type, which allows users to specify a fixed target width. In the code below, I set this width to `4em` for all 5 columns; you're obviously free to adjust this number to suit your typesetting needs. Aside: After widening the columns, you may want to keep an eye on whether the table still fits inside the text block. The width of the text block is given by the parameter `\textwidth`.
- With the  `array`, `makecell`, `siunitx` and `mhchem` packages:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}    % for 'w' column type
\usepackage{makecell} % for '\makecell' macro
\usepackage[per-mode = symbol]{siunitx} % for '\unit' macro
\usepackage[version=4]{mhchem} % for '\ce' macro

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{ w{c}{4em} *{4}{>{$}w{c}{4em}<{$}} }
    \cline{1-3}
    & \makecell{y \\ e}  
    & \makecell{\kappa \\ \unit{eV\per\square\angstrom}}\\
    \hline
    \ce{Na^+}   &  -0.5056  &  63.014   &   &   \\
    \ce{Cl^-}   &  -2.5005  &  25.724   &   &   \\
    \hline
    1           & 2         &  3        & 4 & 5 \\ 
    \hline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

**Addendum:**

- combination of the both tables, with the  `tabularray` with libraries `booktabs` and `siunitx`, and `mathtools` and `mhchem` packages:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs, siunitx}
\sisetup{per-mode = symbol,
         group-minimum-digits=4}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\DeclarePairedDelimiter\abs{\lvert}{\rvert}
\usepackage[version=4]{mhchem}

\begin{document}

\begin{tblr}{width = 0.8\linewidth, 
             colspec={@{} X[l]
                      X[c, si={table-format=-1.4}]
                      X[c, si={table-format= 2.3}]
                      X X
                      @{} },
             row{1} ={guard},
             row{2-Z} = {rowsep=1pt}
             }
    \cmidrule[\heavyrulewidth]{1-3}
    & {$y$ \\ $\abs{e}$}
    & {$\kappa$ \\ (\unit{eV\per\square\angstrom}})\\
    \cmidrule{1-3}
\ce{Na^+}   &  -0.5056  &  63.014   &   &   \\
\ce{Cl^-}   &  -2.5005  &  25.724   &   &   \\
\end{tblr}

\begin{tblr}{width = 0.8\linewidth, 
             colspec={@{} X[l]
                          X[c, si={table-format=6.0}]
                          X[c, si={table-format=1.5}]
                          X[c, si={table-format=2.2}]
                          X[c, si={table-format=3.1}]
                      @{} },
             row{1} ={guard},
             row{2-Z} = {rowsep=1pt}
             }
    \toprule
    & {A\\ (\unit{\electronvolt})}
                & {$\rho$\\ (\unit{\angstrom})}
                            & {C\\  (\unit{\angstrom\electronvolt^6})}
                                    & {D\\  (\unit{\angstrom\electronvolt^8})}
                                            \\
    \midrule
\ce{Na - Na} 
    &    587    & 0.23768   &  1.05 &   0.5 \\
\ce{Na - Cl}
    & 145134    & 0.23768   &  6.99 &   8.7 \\
\ce{Cl - Cl}
    & 406587    & 0.23768   & 72.40 & 145.4 \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tblr}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @Zhao Dazhuang, see edited answer.

Comment: +1. I've taken the liberty of editing your text a bit. Feel free to revert.

Comment: @Mico, thank you very much for editing! Now explanation is far better.